# Modal html reading characters in data as html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page with a modal popup with customer data. The data is passed as a JSON string, however sometimes the data contains characters like '<' that is intrepeted as an unclosed html tag, and the remaining data doesn't show. How can I force it to intrepret my json as a literal? Snippet of the modal initialization and sample data below:

```
$scope.showModal = function() {
  $('#customerDetailModal').modal();
  $('#customerDetailModal .modal-body').html(JSON.stringify(sortJSONObject($scope.customer),null,4));
};

"{
    "customerId": "customer1",
    "test": "test<testtest",
    "field1": "value1"
}"
```

Comment: Try using $('#customerDetailModal .modal-body').text instead of html. jquery automatically html encodes any string entered as text.

Comment: This worked for what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have no HTML tags in the data.

Personally I think the best practice would be to use a regex to replace all instances of "<" and ">" with their html equivalents. Here is a [link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for the html codes.

var str = "<";

console.log(str.replace(/\x3C/g, "`&lt;`").replace(/\x3E/g, "`&gt;`"));

the /\x/g replace allows you to select characters by their hexadecimal code.

**OTHERWISE**
if you need to show html on occasions AngularJS actually has an HTML sanitizer in the [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).